# how to create a popover when someone move cursor over an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to show a movable popover with some links and info when someone move cursor over an image. I'm using Bootstrap 3.

Here is an example....  http://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/logo-design-naming-contest-25538/entries#contest-breadcrumbs

In this example when someone move the cursor over an image a popover has been appear.

I want to create something like this.

```
                                .............Sohag
```

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: User modalpopup control

Comment: You can always check what this people are using by inspecting their scripts, or you can find some jquery tooltip plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try using `tooltipster` or you can create your own jquery function for this.
this link will help you.

[tooltip image](http://www.dyn-web.com/code/tooltips/image_text.php)

[tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/)

if you are ready to pay $6, then this plugin is really very good.

[codecanyon smart image tooltip](http://codecanyon.net/item/smart-image-tooltip/full_screen_preview/5139513)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"></a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
 'showCloseButton': false
 }).hover(function() {
  $(this).click();
  $(".fancybox-overlay").mouseout(function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Prateek19/NvpVT/82/)